# Is connectedness relative property

Tags: real-analysis, definition, connectedness

I am bit confused after reading definition 2.45 from baby Rudin.

> 2.45   Definition   Two subsets A and B of a metric space X are said to be separated if both A∩B¯ and A¯∩B are empty, i.e., if no point of A lies in the closure of B and no point of B lies in the closure of A. A set E⊂X is said to be connected if E is not a union of two nonempty separated sets.

Suppose, $E\subset X$. Is statement '$E$ is connected in $X$' makes sense? I mean is connectedness is also relative property? I consider example $E=(0,1) \cup (1,2)$ as subset of $R$. Then $E$ is not connected in $E$, but connected in $R$. So in Rudin's definition it is not clear to me if author saying connected 'in E' or 'in X'.

Comment: What do you mean by $E$ being connected in $\mathbb{R}$? In the sense that the two components aren't separated?

Comment: Oh.. i messed up badly

Comment: No worries --- it's an intrinsic part of doing math :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you see $E$ as a subset of $\Bbb R$, the $E$ is disconnected, since $\overline{(0,1)}\cap(1,2)=(0,1)\cap\overline{(1,2)}=\emptyset$. And, no, connectedness is not a relative property. That is, if $(X,\tau)$ is a topological space and if $Y\subset X$, then $Y$ is connected in $Y$ with respect to the subspace topology if and only if $Y$ is connected in $X$.